# Output FLANN results in python

Tags: python, opencv, flann, flannbasedmatcher

I am currently implementing LSH using FLANN.

```
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,k=2)
```

des1 is a binary descriptor of my query image & flann is the flanbasedmatcher (using the FLANN LSH algo) variable which has all the binary descriptor of an image database.

How do I output the result of the knnMatch?

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? According to their [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html), it need 2 descriptors to check for the matching. PS: You can find how to display the result in the link, too.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look to this [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/plane_tracker.py)
It's an opencv sample showing how to use a FlannBasedMatcher.
There is a lot of topics talking about this, you should search better before asking.

**Edit**

I assume you have a FLANN Index to match with `des1`, so there is a function that returns if there is a match or not.

```
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
def flann_match(des1):
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, k=2)
    # Check the distance to keep only the good matches.
    matches = [m[0] for m in matches if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * 0.75]
    if len(matches < MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
        return False
    return True
```

This implementation is quite simple, you'll need to use `cv2.findHomography()` ([documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography)) to get better and more accurate results, depends of what is your goal here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are completely right, but I thought there was too much code to paste here to make any sense. This link is from opencv docs, I don't think it will become unavailable. Just in case, you can find this file in opencv 2.4 : `<path_to_opencv_folder>/samples/python2/plane_tracker.py`

Comment: the link is broken